# How to apply fading effect for last 2-3 lines when it is exceeding certain specified lines

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to apply the fading effect in the font colors when it exceeds some certain specified number of lines. In the specified example in card with "ReportTitle 1" I wanted to have the fading effect from the line 8. But in the below card with "ReportTitle 2" it shouldn't have any fading effects applied because it didn't exceeded the specified number of lines i.e. 8 in the example. In case if there are some cards(div) which has only less number of lines less than 7, then NO fading effect should be applied.
[image]

```
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent 100px, #447294, #fff);
```

I searched in the net, but I am getting examples with the background color changing to white or to any other colors. But since I am having a differnt background color in the "Card" i.e. div, i wanted to have the effect on the font color only and not on the background color.
Please refer the working example in the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/snkrishnan1/5vv4ofa7/4/)

any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add class `.card:after` with position absolute at bottom:

```
.card:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 5em;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, white, transparent);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, white, transparent);
}
```

[here is jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgp861cb/)

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning in my original question, apologies, I do have a footer section which has some blue background. When I try to apply the css given by you, it even shades/fades out the footer color also. I don't want the footer color and its CSS to be affected or faded out. Only the text contents should be faded, what changes to be done for this? Please refer https://jsfiddle.net/5vv4ofa7/7/

Comment: try this: https://jsfiddle.net/z4gtfh32/ . here is gradient color mix to text, without :after selector

Comment: footer overlaps text. is it correct? or should it below faded bottom of text block?

Comment: it seems last link fiddle is coser to aim. look here https://jsfiddle.net/Lgp861cb/ if it's that you want, then I'll change the answer