# button not fix at the bottom of the div in my div's

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

[here the image that is result i m getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxfOk.png)

[Expected result i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeC9z.png)

My html page has collection of div where each 3 divs are place in one  row and the next row consist of next 3 divs and the height of the div are same for all the 3 div's in the row and that i have done using flex but i have to position a button right at the bottom of the page but not able to place it at the bottom for the div where the content are dynamic in nature

i have tried using position:relative of the main div and making the button postion:absolute but my data then is hidden by the button

Comment: it would be better if you could show us your codes

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/faisalpathan/he2owrar/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41192579/4206079

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you contain all your code in One div name wrap, and  button is outside of it.

So,in the main div whatever the height of button may be supposed its 89px.

You can fix the button as:

```
.wrap {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 89px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.button_div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.shipping-content-div
{
    position: relativ; 
    height: 100%;
}

<div class="button_div">
    <button class="form-control btn-default btn btn-click">Click</button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/he2owrar/2/

Comment: i have attach a image this code to hide the content because position is absolute

Comment: add this: `.shipping-content-adress { margin-bottom: 30px; }` check how much margin you need for a good look :-)